# Loop through column and stop at a certain condition (python)

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, rows, continue

I have a dataframe similar to below,

```
Date            A  B
2017-01-01      1  1
2017-01-02      2  2
2017-01-03      1  2
```

For each column, I want to test the condition A==B for each name in the groupby statement. If this condition does not hold true, I want to print "Condition ends at 2017-01-03." I'm not sure how to loop through each row in this dataframe. I'm envisioning something like this code, although I know I am not itterating through the correct thing:

```
for i in df.Date:
    if df.A == df.B:
        continue
    if df.A != df.B:
        print ("Condition ends at", i)
```

Comment: Not really the answer, but you could skip the checking the equality of the A and B, and only keep the “not equal” check.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas).

You would be iterating through each row and then accessing the appropriate column as a key, in this way you can compare column to each other in each row

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
print 'Condition ends at', (df.A.values != df.B.values).argmax()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the nice pythonic syntax:

```
print next([d for d in dates if d.A != d.B], None)
```

The None would be the default value if none is found